# Workaround EACCES (Permission denied) with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE und requestLegacyExternalStorage

Tags: android, permissions

if you have Problem with file permissions, following solution worked for me on API 27, 29 and 30. I haven't tried for API version 28 but I assume it would also work for 28 because the file access rights are changed from API version 29.

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**,

```
<manifest
  ...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  ...
  <application
    ...
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    >
  ...
  </application>

</manifest>
```

***main.java***,

```
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1240;
private ArrayList<String> appPermissions;
private  ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> permissionLauncher;

private void checkPermissionsGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        if ( !Environment.isExternalStorageManager() ) {
            requestPermission();

        } else {
            // app has permissions, init app
            initApp();
        }

    } else {
        // older API-Versions
        checkAndRequestPermissions();
    }
}


private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // app has permissions, init app
                        initApp();

                    } else {
                        //permission is denied
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            //   startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
            permissionLauncher.launch(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exp... " + e.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            permissionLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    }
}

public void checkAndRequestPermissions(){

    // check which permissions are granted
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String perm:appPermissions){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(perm);
        }
    }

    // ask for non-granted
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

    } else {
        // app has all permissions, init app
        initApp();
    }
}

private void initApp() {
    /**
     * TODO
     * */
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> permissionResults = new HashMap<>();
        int deniedCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                permissionResults.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                deniedCount++;
            }
        }

        if (deniedCount == 0) {
            // app has all permissions, init app
            initApp();

        } else {
            // denied
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : permissionResults.entrySet()) {
                String permName = entry.getKey();
                int permResult = entry.getValue();

                // permission is denied (this is first time, when "newer ask again" is not checked)
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permName)) {
                    // show dialog
                    new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.confirmation_permissions))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm_permissions_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            checkAndRequestPermissions();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.confirm_permissions_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            // finish App
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();

                } else {
                    //permission is denied ("newer ask again" is checked)
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```